# Динамический Pattern в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Есть запрос на внешний сервис, этот сервис подтягивает мне определенные поля и с каждым полем его `pattern`, в след. виде:

```
[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{1,100}

[0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{2,10}
```

В квадратных скобках мне присылают разрешенные для ввода символы, а в фигурных минимальное и максимальное количество цифр.

В итоге у меня в шаблоне есть ряд полученных полей у каждого из них есть `pattern`.

Как мне проверить валидность введенных данных, в соответствии с пришедшим паттерном.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогли разобраться:

```
var s = "hello123";

var r1 = "[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{1,100}";
var reg1 = RegExp("^" + r1 + "$");

var r2 = "[0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{2,10}";
var reg2 = RegExp("^" + r2 + "$");

alert(reg1.test(s)); // false
alert(reg2.test(s)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = new RegExp("[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{1,100} [0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'+-]{2,10}");
var string = "lkvjasdfdlkvk 4342";
var result = string.match(pattern);
if (result != null) {
    // подходит
} else {
    // не подходит
}
```

Comment: Эффективнее использовать `test()`